# when applying ingest pipeline it fails with parse execption request body or source parameter is required

Tags: elasticsearch

Execute this request

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/add_test_pipeline
{
  "description": "A description for your pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "fieldname",
        "value": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and get error:

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "request body or source parameter is required"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "request body or source parameter is required"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

request works on one cluster but does not on another.

[From discuss.elastic.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/when-applying-ingest-pipeline-it-fails-with-parse-execption-request-body-is-required/230788)
this page from google can not open.

[image: request execute screenshot]

[image: pending tasks]

Comment: show how you use the pipeline.

Comment: @rabbitbr I get the error when create the pipeline. not when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

When you issue the PUT command to create a new document using your pipeline, you need to specify the document int he request body:

```
PUT filebeat-7.6.2-2020.05.02-000001/_doc/ny1z03EBxpMbNnRZgGlQ?pipeline= add_test_pipeline
```

...will not work and produce the error you're seeing because you're not sending any document in the body. The pipeline alone will not create a document out of the blue, you need to provide one, even if it's empty like this:

```
PUT filebeat-7.6.2-2020.05.02-000001/_doc/ny1z03EBxpMbNnRZgGlQ?pipeline= add_test_pipeline
{
}
```

Comment: I get the error when create the pipeline. not when to use it.

Comment: Where are you executing this command?

Comment: Kibana, develop tool

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and share it? You must not have an empty line between PUT and the body

Comment: The same request works on develop environment. And there's no empty line between PUT and body.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the request and response window please and share it?

Comment: I have taken a screenshot above.

Comment: Interesting... also why does this simple request take 29 seconds to carry out ?

Comment: It seems have something else happened when parsing body, and take 30s to timeout. But return the error mislead us.

Comment: What happens if you run the same query with curl ? `curl -XPUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' http://localhost:9200/_ingest/pipeline/add_test_pipeline -d '{...}'` ?

Comment: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"process_cluster_event_timeout_exception","reason":"failed to process cluster event (put-pipeline-add_test_pipeline) within 30s"}],"type":"process_cluster_event_timeout_e
xception","reason":"failed to process cluster event (put-pipeline-add_test_pipeline) within 30s"},"status":503}

Comment: I can't get any error message in master's log.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the cluster is very busy and your request times out (`process_cluster_event_timeout_exception`). Can you manage to make the following request and update your question with the response you get ? `GET _cat/pending_tasks?v`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251852/discussion-between-elapsedsoul-and-val).

Comment: It looks like you have plenty of ILM tasks standing in queue waiting to be processed 

Comment: It seems to be that, it run well when there's no pending task. so how to optimize this like making the pipeline task high priority.

Comment: Ok, then the question should be closed as this is another problem that has nothing to do with the original problem. Feel free to close this one and open a new question describing the underlying context.